# java manifest file have maven-xxxxx.jar dependency jar files included

Tags: java, maven

I try to build a manifest file from maven using maven-jar-plugin. What i see is that some maven-?????.jar files are includes. How can I exclude these mave jar dependency files

for example lib/maven-project-2.2.0.jar and lib/maven-dependency-tree
 -2.1.jar

see below my manifest file (the claspath )

thanks

Johan

```
Class-Path: lib/ecs-utilities-1.0.0.jar lib/gtos-aybm-1.0.0.jar lib/sp
 ring-jdbc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar lib/sp
 ring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar lib/spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar lib/geron
 imo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar lib/hazelcast-clie
 nt-3.8.1.jar lib/hazelcast-3.8.1.jar lib/ecs-data-contract-1.0.0.jar 
 lib/ecs-rdt-data-contract-1.0.0.jar lib/ecs-modbus-1.0.0.jar lib/ecs-
 config-1.0.0.jar lib/j2mod-2.3.3.jar lib/jSerialComm-1.3.11.jar lib/P
 CANBasic-1.0.jar lib/RXTXcomm-1.0.jar lib/gson-2.8.0.jar lib/guava-21
 .0.jar lib/guice-4.1.0.jar lib/javax.inject-1.jar lib/aopalliance-1.0
 .jar lib/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
  lib/activemq-broker-5.14.4.jar lib/activemq-client-5.14.4.jar lib/ha
 wtbuf-1.11.jar lib/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar lib/ac
 tivemq-openwire-legacy-5.14.4.jar lib/commons-io-2.5.jar lib/commons-
 collections4-4.1.jar lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar lib/log4j-api-2.6.2.ja
 r lib/log4j-core-2.6.2.jar lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar lib/slf4j-api-
 1.7.12.jar lib/sonar-maven-plugin-4.5.1.jar lib/maven-dependency-tree
 -2.1.jar lib/maven-project-2.2.0.jar lib/maven-settings-2.2.0.jar lib
 /maven-profile-2.2.0.jar lib/maven-model-2.2.0.jar lib/maven-artifact
 -manager-2.2.0.jar lib/maven-repository-metadata-2.2.0.jar lib/wagon-
 provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar lib/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar lib/
 maven-plugin-registry-2.2.0.jar lib/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar lib
 /plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar lib/maven-artifact-2.2.0.jar lib/plexus-cont
 ainer-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar lib/plexus-component-annotatio
 ns-1.5.5.jar lib/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar lib/sonar-runner-api-2.4.ja
 r
```

Here is my pom file

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>pre-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.apache.maven,org.codehaus.sonar,org.codehaus.plexus,org.testfx,org.reflections</excludeGroupIds>
                        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>nl.ict.psa.eqp.sc_rdt.MainApplication</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Title>PSA ECS SCRDT</Implementation-Title>
                        <Implementation-Version>3.0.0</Implementation-Version>
                        <Implementation-Vendor>ICT Automatisering Nederland B.V.</Implementation-Vendor>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.exe</exclude>
                    <exclude>*.bat</exclude>
                    <exclude>assembly/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>css/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build fat jar?

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: I added the plugins of my pom file